# Multithreading in Bash

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell

I would like to introduce multithreading feature in my shell script.

I have a script which calls the function `read_cfg()` with different arguments.
Each of these function calls are independent.

Would it be possible to instantiate these function calls (not scripts) parallelly.
Please let me how can we achieve that.. ?

Comment: This is not multithreading -- it's multiprocessing. Each instance is run in a distinct process, copied from the original with `fork()`. These processes -- unlike threads -- have their own file descriptor tables, and their memory is copy-on-write (so when they change a variable's value, the parent process doesn't see it).

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Sure, just add `&` after the command:

```
read_cfg cfgA &
read_cfg cfgB &
read_cfg cfgC &
wait
```

all those jobs will then run in the background simultaneously. The optional `wait` command will then wait for all the jobs to finish.

Each command will run in a separate process, so it's technically not "multithreading", but I believe it solves your problem.

Comment: You should read up the difference between process and thread. What you propose is not multithreading - it involves separate processes for every  command.

Comment: @TomTom: I certainly know the difference between processes and threads. If you see through the OP's choice of words, I believe he is simply asking whether it's possible to run the commands in parallel (which is possible). I added a note about this to clarify.

Comment: It can be slow if you have an high amount of process

Answer (score 39):

You can run several copies of your script in parallel, each copy for different input data, e.g. to process all *.cfg files on 4 cores:

```
    ls *.cfg | xargs -P 4 -n 1 read_cfg.sh
```

The read_cfg.sh script takes just one parameters (as enforced by -n)

Comment: just a note that you should specify the full path to `read_cfg.sh` or `xargs` will say it can't find the file.

Comment: Better to use `printf '%s\0' *.cfg | xargs -0 ...` -- that way this works with filenames with spaces, unprintable characters, etc. See also [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 30):

Bash job control involves multiple processes, not multiple threads.

You can execute a command in background with the `&` suffix.

You can wait for completion of a background command with the `wait` command.

You can execute multiple commands in parallel by separating them with `|`. This provides also a synchronization mechanism, since stdout of a command at left of `|` is connected to stdin of command at right.