# Multithreading Bash If Statements

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, unix

What is the correct way to multithread independent `if` statements in a bash script? Is it best to place the `&` after code contained in the `if` or after the expression?

For an `&` after the expression, it makes sense to continue threading as necessary if the `if` contains a large block of code. But should one line of code also end with `&`?

After the expression:

```
if [ expression ] &
  then
    #task
fi
```

After the task:

```
if [ expression ]
  then
    #task &
fi
```

Imagine 3 `if` statements that all perform tasks independent of each other, how does the execution work with the different placement of the `&`? From what I understand, if placed after the expression, all 3 expressions start (basically) simultaneously and so do the 3 tasks.

```
#Thread 1         #Thread 2         #Thread 3
if [ expr1 ] &    if [ expr2 ] &    if [ expr3 ] &
  then              then              then
    task1            task2            task3
fi                fi                fi
wait
```

If placed after the task code, the first `if` would be evaluated and only as the first task begins would the 2nd `if` be evaluated. The tasks are more staggered than simultaneous.

```
#Thread 1         #Thread 2         #Thread 3
if [ expr1 ]
  then
    task1 &       if [ expr2 ]
fi                  then
                      task2 &       if [ expr3 ]
                  fi                  then
                                        task3 &
                                    fi
wait
```

The expressions *cannot* be combined to do threading inside the `if` such as:

```
if [ combined expression ]
  then
    #task1 &
    #task2 &
    #task3 &
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want each `if` condition to execute within the context of its respective "thread" (actually subshell process), then I think the thing to do is put the `&` after the closing `fi` statement for each `if`.  Then the evaluation of each `if` expression, along with conditional code wiil occur entirely within the context of its own "thread".

For example:

```
#/bin/bash

if [ 1 ] 
  then
    for i1 in {1..3}; do echo $i1; sleep 1; done
fi &
if [ 1 ]
  then
    for i2 in {a..c}; do echo $i2; sleep 1; done
fi &
wait
```

Output from each "thread" is interleaved as expected:

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

Note in all cases with `&`, these are actually processes (created with `fork()`) and not threads (created with `pthread_create()`).  See [Multithreading in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425870/multithreading-in-bash?rq=1).  You can test this by creating a variable, e.g. `n=0` before the "threads" are started.  Then in one thread increment n and echo $n in all threads.  You'll see each "thread" gets its own copy of n - n will have different values in the incrementing and non-incrementing threads.  `fork()` creates a new process copy (including independent copies of variables); `pthread_create()` doesn't.

Comment: In my specific case, I think it is fine that they are separate processes. Does `wait` just end child processes when they finish then?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  `wait` blocks until all child sub-processes have completed.  So if you have any more statements after the `wait`, then these statements won't execute until all the sub-processes have completed.  `wait` can also take a pid or job id if you want to wait for a specific subprocess to end.  You can get the pid of subprocesses from the built-in `$!` variable right after backgrounding with `&`.

Answer (score 5):

Placing the `&` after the `if` will only background the evaluation of the conditional expression ; `[` is actually an alias for the `test` command, and that is what will be backgrouded, and not the task.

Placing the `&` after the task will background the task. The degree to which the tasks are staggered rather than simultaneous depends on the relative time needed to evaluate `expr1` compared to the time needed to perform `task1`

See the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ 1 ] &
then
    sleep 10 
fi
if [ 1 ] &
then
    sleep 10 
fi
if [ 1 ] &
then
    sleep 10 
fi
wait
```

it takes 30 seconds to run

```
$ time . test.sh 
[3]   Done                    [ 1 ]
[3]   Done                    [ 1 ]
[3]   Done                    [ 1 ]

real    0m30.015s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.012s
```

and you see that the backgrounded task is `[ 1 ]`, not `sleep`. Note that is is meaningless as explained by @chepner.

Now the other case:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ 1 ] 
then
    sleep 10 &
fi
if [ 1 ] 
then
    sleep 10 &
fi
if [ 1 ] 
then
    sleep 10 &
fi
wait
```

gives:

```
[2]   Done                    sleep 10
[3]   Done                    sleep 10
[4]-  Done                    sleep 10

real    0m10.197s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.014s
```

It only takes 10 seconds ; all the `sleeps` are simultaneous as they are being backgrounded.

Last option as described by @DigitalTrauma:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ 1 ] 
then
    sleep 10 
fi &
if [ 1 ]
then
    sleep 10 
fi &
if [ 1 ] 
then
    sleep 10
fi &
wait
```

Then the whole `if` statement is backgrounded, i.e. both the evaluation of `exprN` and of `taskN`

```
[3]   Done                    if [ 1 ]; then
    sleep 10;
fi
[4]   Done                    if [ 1 ]; then
    sleep 10;
fi
[5]   Done                    if [ 1 ]; then
    sleep 10;
fi

real    0m10.017s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.013s
```

giving the expected 10 seconds running time

Answer (score 4):

Compare

```
if false
then
  echo "condition true"
fi
```

with

```
if false &
then
  echo "condition ... true?"
fi
```

A command terminated by `&` exits immediately with status 0, so the `if` branch is taken regardless of what the background process eventually returns. It doesn't make sense to put a command that unconditionally succeeds in the command list of an `if` statement. You have to let it complete so the body can be correctly (conditionally) executed.

Comment: I wondered if that would happen. I thought `&` proceeds with the next line of code, but thought the next line read was after the `fi`. I think DigitalTrauma's answer still allows the if to be evaluated.

Comment: Yes, his answer is correct. This is just an explanation of why you can't background the condition only.

Answer (score 0):

the answers so far rely on using spawning 3 and waiting for all 3 to complete before starting again.

a "better" way in bash is using the `jobs` command like so

`jobs|wc -l` and then looping with a small sleep command like so

(not tested code)

```
 while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
if [[$(jobs | wc-l`) < 3 ]] then 

    expression &
    fi
    sleep 10;

done
```

that will allow all 3 "threads" to be filled without waiting for all 3 to complete before refilling