# How can I do "git pull" in multithreading or efficient way?

Tags: multithreading, git, bash

I have one directory called 'projects' which is the parent directory, within that near by 200 sub-directories which are my projects.

For now I am executting `git pull` by following script.

```
#!/bin/bash  
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c "cd \"{}\"/../ && pwd && git pull && echo -e '-------------------- \n ' " \;
```

Is there any efficient way I can do this process in multithreading and faster way?

Comment: Use `xargs` or `parallel` with the list of directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All sub-directory are not having same git repository and also its not [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). So for now I am solving this problem by [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) which is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d -name '.git' -print0 | xargs -P 40 -n 1 -0 -I '{}' sh -c "cd \"{}\"/../ && git pull && pwd && echo -e '-------------------- \n ' " \;
```

- `find .` - Start find from current working directory (recursively by default)
- `-type d -name '.git'` - Finding all directories having **.git** directory as sub-directory.
- `-print0` - List of directories as input to xargs

I also found some good help at 
http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/7

Answer (score 1):

Note that if your nested repos were declared as **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, then a simple `git submodule update --remote` would be enough.

That is, provided you had [your submodules configured to follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).
See also "[Git submodule to track remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016830/6309)".

Those updates (involving a pull) would not be multithreaded though ([both for the checkout part](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/256317), but for the fetch part as well.

The multi-threading is only for *one* operation, as mentioned [in this thread](http://lists-archives.com/git/800106-is-git-multithreaded.html):

> A few selected operations are multi-threaded if you compile with
>   thread support (i.e., do not set `NO_PTHREADS` when you build).
>
> But object packing (used during fetch/push, and during `git-gc`) is multi-threaded (at least the delta compression portion of it is).
>
> git may fork to perform certain asynchronous operations.
>   E.g., during a fetch, one process runs pack-objects to create the output, and the other speaks the git protocol, mostly just passing through the output to the client.
>   On systems with threads, some of these operations are performed using a thread rather than fork.
>   This is  not about CPU performance, but about keeping the code simple (and cannot be controlled with config).

---

All that means, as [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) comments, that you would need to script those git pull updates yourself in order to multithread those commands.

See "[Multithreading in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425870/6309)" for scripting solution.

Comment: While this contains a fair bit of generally useful information it doesn't actually deal with the situation in the OP's question at all or offer anything by way of a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @EtanReisner because as far as I know there is no git-native solution: multiple git pull are not multithreaded by default.

Comment: His repositories are unrelated (it would seem). You don't need a git-native solution. You postulated a situation that doesn't exist and which painted yourself into a problem that needn't exist.